# What is required to generate code coverage data using XCode 4

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, llvm-gcc, coverstory

I have been trying to generate code coverage data for my application on XCode 4.2.1 (build 4D502) using the steps outlined at http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/UsingCoverstory

I am obviously missing something as there are no .gcno or .gcda files being generated along side my object files.  I've tried adding the settings to both my test target and my application target but to no avail.  I've had a second set of eyes go over things and all appears to be in order. Any ideas as to what is missing.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work with llvm-gcc; you'll need to use the "LLVM Compiler 3.0" (aka clang). (I assume by the 'llvm-gcc' tag that you're not currently using it.)

I did this just last week, so it's definitely working.

Comment: Thanks BJ. You are right on. I'm a newbie to Apple development and from what I could see it looked as if using the LLVM compiler instead of the GCC compiler meant to use the LLVM-GCC compiler.  I didn't realize that I had three different compiler choices.  Thanks again.

Comment: +1: I used this to help solve my own problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8622293/293511