# No code coverage with Mac OS X Lion and XCode 4 / llvm-g++-4.2

Tags: macos, gcov, llvm-gcc

Other people have reported not being able to [generate code coverage with XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097951/code-coverage-gcov-not-working-with-xcode-4-2-and-ios-sdk-5/), but I find not only can I not do it from within XCode 4, I can't do it even with a simple toy program from the command line. I followed the examples given [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_81.html) and [here](http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/code-coverage-with-gcov), which led me to create this cov.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      if (i % 3 == 0)
        printf("%d is divisible by 3\n", i);
      if (i % 11 == 0)
        printf("%d is divisible by 11\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I then used the following commands in an attempt to generate code coverage:

```
g++ -c -g -O0 --coverage -o $PWD/obj/cov.o $PWD/cov.c
g++ -g -O0 --coverage -o $PWD/bin/cov $PWD/obj/*.o
$PWD/bin/cov
```

Alas, no cov.gcno file exists in the obj directory. In fact, the only files I have after this are:
cov.c
obj/cov.o
bin/cov

Furthermore, if I type `nm bin/cov`, I get the following:

```
0000000100001048 S _NXArgc
0000000100001050 S _NXArgv
0000000100001060 S ___progname
0000000100000000 A __mh_execute_header
0000000100001058 S _environ
                 U _exit
0000000100000e40 T _main
                 U _printf
0000000100001000 s _pvars
                 U dyld_stub_binder
0000000100000e00 T start
```

This suggests that libgcov.a was never linked in. If I replace

```
g++ -g -O0 --coverage -o $PWD/bin/cov $PWD/obj/*.o
```

with:

```
g++ -g -O0 --coverage -o $PWD/bin/cov -lgcov $PWD/obj/*.o
```

I get the exact same results.

More information:

- `g++ --version` yields: "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1
  (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)"
- I've also tried using gcc (which is llvm-gcc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out an answer to this question using help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407338/293511). Basically, I changed my coverage commands to use `clang` instead of `g++` (because the example file was pure C, I went with `clang` instead of `clang++`, which I've verified works just fine with C++ files). From there, I was able to use lcov to generate output similar to what I'm used to seeing from Java/cobertura.

Answer (score 2):

On Lion `g++` is an alias for `llvm-g++`, as you have discovered.  To invoke "real" gcc, use `gcc-4.2` or `g++-4.2`:

```
g++-4.2 -g -O0 --coverage -o $PWD/bin/cov $PWD/obj/*.o
```

Comment: Alas, there is no g++-4.2 on my system. However, there is clang++, which seems to do the trick.